# How to remove text from html outside tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are double parenthesis in my HTML. Don't know where they come from but kinda annoying. Tried to remove it but didn't work. Need to scroll to the end to be able to see the parenthesis

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="form-group" style="display:none">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="label-wrapper">
            <label class="control-label" for="Id">Id</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="form-text-row">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ))

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="label-wrapper">
            <label class="control-label" for="Title">Title</label>
            <div title="Please enter the title" data-toggle="tooltip" class="ico-help">
                <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Title" name="Title" type="text" value="Sample Title">
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Title" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript to remove parenthesis:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var text = $('.panel-body').text();
    text.replace('))', '');
});
```

but didn't do anything at all.

Comment: You get a copy of the text and then you update that copy, the original text inside the `.panel-body` element is never changed.

Comment: *"idk where they come from"* - Wouldn't it be better to figure that out rather than removing them from JS? Is the HTML of the page generated by some other system, or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.panel-body').html( $('.panel-body').html().replace('))', '') ); 
});
```

Comment: The second line: `text.replace('))', '');` can squarely be removed... For the same result.

Comment: sorry about that I forgot that line thank you very much for mentioning my mistake :)

Comment: You can use `.html(function)` instead

Comment: @ahmedabdullah ty for your answer. this works fine if I use this function. I have a toggle function as well. This is messing up my toggle function also input html